Cannot find file at 'c:\python312\python.exe' (c:\python312\python.exe). This usually indicates a missing or moved file
Why do I get this message with every version of Python, when trying to create a venv? It appeared suddenly. It used to work fine. Appreciate how mysterious the following screenshot is:

The first one command is referring to python 3.12 - I checked.
I installed the Pythons with Microsoft Store, which is fine; I know where the executables are (in AppData\Local\WindowsApps...).
Only the 3.12 is installed with chocolatey (by another program I think). Path is C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\python3.12.exe.
By the way, I asked Windows to install the metro apps on Drive E but it does not seem to care..
Another weird thing:

I ran Get-Command on python 3.12 and it yielded Chocolatey's install path.
I uninstalled chocolatey's python
I restarted my terminal
I deleted my pycache
still the same message !! - when I run python3.12 and python.

